# Dealloc of custom object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this Class in my project :

```
        @interface VideoItem : NSObject <NSCoding> {
              NSString *name;
              NSString *artist;
              int seconds;
        }

        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imgUrl;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *artist;

        @end
```

And this is how i create this object:

```
    VideoItem *item = [[VideoItem alloc] init];
    item.name = name;
    item.imgUrl = imgLink;
    item.artist = artist;
```

And this is the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [name release];
    [imgUrl release];
    [artist release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

And i want to know if this `dealoc` is ok with the `NON-ARC`? did i need to do something else because this `NSString` are with Property?

## Edit

And if the VideoItem object was create with:

```
VideoItem *item = [[VideoItem alloc] init];
        item.name = [NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",name];
        item.imgUrl = [NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",imgLink];
        item.artist = [NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",artist];
```

Did in this case the dealloc is still ok? or i need to change something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks ok, you are releasing all the `@properties` of your object. I would probably as well point them to nil, just to make sure, that if one of those properties is called, it will be nilled and not have a garbage value, like so:

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [name release], name = nil;
    [imgUrl release], imgUrl = nil;
    [artist release], artist = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Another thing, no related, it would be cleaner, if you would create your own init, so you can pass the properties values, when you actually create the object, like so:

```
-initWithName:(NSString *)name withImgURL:(NSString *)imgURL withArtist:(NSString *)artist;
```

---

Your edit:

```
item.name = [NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",name];
item.imgUrl = [NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",imgLink];
item.artist = [NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",artist];
```

Only based on this, it will create a leak, so you should be careful. To fix this:

```
item.name = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",name] autorelease];
item.imgUrl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",imgLink] autorelease];
item.artist = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat@"%@",artist] autorelease];
```

Comment: I edit my question with some other stuff, and thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ARC enabled than your destructor is correct. You are releasing all the properties that are retained and calling super, which is all you need.